# Use tkinter library from a virtual environment when using pyenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, tkinter, asdf

I am trying to use a library that relies on tkinter ([inky](https://pypi.org/project/inky/), in mock mode).

My development environment consists of debian bookworm with python 3.12 (installed using asdf, a pyenv-like tool) and a virtual environment created from this runtime using `python -m venv .venv`.

The python 3.12 runtime was installed **after** installing the `tk-dev` libs so the module was compiled and if I run `python -m tkinter` using that runtime, it works and I can see the tk test window.
Looking into details, the cpython bridge dynamic library is present at `/home/joel/.asdf/installs/python/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_tkinter.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.
Running `ldd` on that file yields the libtk8.6.so file as expected, and that file is present on my system:

```
$ ldd ~/.asdf/installs/python/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_tkinter.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff1671e000)
    libtk8.6.so => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtk8.6.so (0x00007f181edbf000)
    ...
```

Now, if I activate the virtualenv and run the same command, I am getting the following error:

```
$ python -m tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 189, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 148, in _get_module_details
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 112, in _get_module_details
  File "/home/joel/.asdf/installs/python/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ImportError: libtk8.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This makes no sense, as both the base interpreter and venv's paths are the same.
With base interpreter:

```
$ python
Python 3.12.1 (main, Jan 14 2024, 12:18:04) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print('\n'.join(sys.path))

/home/joel/.asdf/installs/python/3.12.1/lib/python312.zip
/home/joel/.asdf/installs/python/3.12.1/lib/python3.12
/home/joel/.asdf/installs/python/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload
/home/joel/.asdf/installs/python/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/site-packages
```

With venv:

```
$ python
Python 3.12.1 (main, Jan 14 2024, 12:18:04) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print('\n'.join(sys.path))

/app/packages/python
/home/joel/.asdf/installs/python/3.12.1/lib/python312.zip
/home/joel/.asdf/installs/python/3.12.1/lib/python3.12
/home/joel/.asdf/installs/python/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload
/home/joel/code/MiniPADD/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages
```

The only differences are:

- `/app/packages/python` path that comes first but there's no such path on my system.
- last path for `site-packages`, which is normal for a venv and should not have an impact as the base interpreter's path only contains `pip`.

I have no idea how to debug this further, there's nothing I can think of that explains why the static lib can be found in the case of the base interpreter but not when the virtual env is active.

How should I go to investigate this in further details?

Comment: Can you list the commands you used to create and activate virtual env ?

Comment: What happens at `import tkinter` if you change `sys.path` within the venv to the other value? Does it work? If not, then it's not `sys.path`. You many want to run `env | sort >a` outside the vm, and then `env | sort >b` inside the venv, end then `diff -u a b`. Maybe another environment variable is different.

Comment: To make this reproducible, show use the commands you use the create and activate the venv. Create a new venv just for this demonstration.

Comment: @Philippe the env was created using `python -m venv .venv`. I also tried using pycharm's UI for that.

Comment: @pts you are right, setting sys.path in the venv to the same value that is produced outside of it still gives the same error.
The env variables are not that different though, the only difference is for $PATH, apart from the obvious venv and prompt ones:

< PATH=/home/joel/.asdf/shims:/home/joel/.asdf/bin:/home/joel/.yarn/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

> PATH=/home/joel/code/MiniPADD/.venv/bin:/home/joel/.asdf/shims:/home/joel/.asdf/bin:/home/joel/.yarn/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

Comment: Ok so I tried creating the venv by disabling asdf, using the system's python and it works. So it looks like the issue comes from the asdf-python plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working... partially.

For some reason, I had to recompile python, using the following env vars:

```
$ export TCLTK_LIBS="$(pkg-config tk --libs)"
$ export TCLTK_CFLAGS="$(pkg-config tk --cflags)"
$ asdf install python 3.12.1
```

I have no idea why this works, python was already compiled with tk enabled since it was working outside the venv, but passing those variables allowed me to make it work from inside the venv.

I still get the same error when running the code from PyCharm, although it is using the same venv as the one that works on the command line...